# StreamReader: Value cannot be null error when reading CSV

Tags: c#, csv, assembly, stream, streamreader

I created a simple console application to use StreamReader to read a CSV file, but it produces the following error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'stream')
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean leaveOpen)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding)
   at StreamCsv.SeedCsv.GetCsvData() in C:\...\StreamCsv\SeedCsv.cs:line 25
   at StreamCsv.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\...\StreamCsv\Program.cs:line 9
watch : Exited with error code -532462766
watch : Waiting for a file to change before restarting dotnet...
```

All of the following files are located in the same folder:

Program.cs -
This is the main program:

```
using System;

namespace StreamCsv
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SeedCsv.GetCsvData();
        }
    }
}
```

SeedCsv.cs - This is the file that calls for StreamReader to process the csv file.  The Build Action of the csv file has been set to Embedded Resource inside .csproj file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CsvHelper;
using StreamCsv.Domain;

namespace StreamCsv
{
    public class SeedCsv
    {
        public static Geocoding[] GetCsvData()
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            string resource = "open_postcode_geo_snippet.csv";

            List<Geocoding> result = new List<Geocoding>();

            using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en"));
                    var data = csvReader.GetRecords<Geocoding>().ToArray();

                    return data;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

StreamCsv.csproj - The csv file has been set to Embedded Resource inside .csproj file, in order to be processed by `assembly.GetManifestResourceStream()`.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="open_postcode_geo_snippet.csv" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CsvHelper" Version="27.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When I run this console, this line of code `using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))` is producing the error `Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'stream')`.

Can anyone point out what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Something you should know about embedded resources: they get qualified by the root namespace and any additional folder structure.  In your case, it looks like it would be `"StreamCsv.open_postcode_geo_snippet.csv"`.

Comment: @madreflection Thank you. You have the right answer. If you post that as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @madreflection I have another question: does the Embedded Resource has to be in the same namespace as the file that uses it?  Can they be in different namespaces?

Comment: Re the follow-up question: Before asking questions like that, you should try it for yourself. Do the science, learn from the effort.